# Combine items in List based on values in another List using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python programming and I wrote a python script to extract all tags and values from a XML and convert it to excel. The problem I'm having is that I need the tags in a specific format. I have the below tags and values in two separate lists.

If the value is not present in a row, then the Tag should be appended to the next one before till we reach a tag that is having a value.
So if the input is

```
Tags            Values
OAuth             
UserAuth 
Vendor          ABC
Time            21.04
AppName
Request         Temporary
```

and the output required is like

```
Tags                           Values
OAuth             
OAuth.UserAuth 
OAuth.UserAuth.Vendor          ABC
OAuth.UserAuth.Time            21.04
AppName
AppName.Request                Temporary
```

Since this does'nt have a fixed repeatable change, I am completely unsure how to proceed doing it with Python. I know this can be done with List comprehension but not sure how.

Comment: Why does it switch to `OAuth.UserAuth.Time` and not just `Time`?

Comment: How do we know that `Time` belongs to `UserAuth` rather than being a new root? This would probably be easier from the original XML instead of this munged version.

Comment: @HughBothwell Apparently the logic is that anything without a value is not a leaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tags = ['OAuth', 'UserAuth', 'Vendor', 'Time', 'AppName', 'Request']
values = ['', '', 'ABC', '21.04', '', 'Temporary']

def parse_tree(tags, values):
    value_found = False
    path = []
    for tag, value in zip(tags, values):
        if value:
            value_found = True
            yield ((".".join(path + [tag])), value)
        else:
            if value_found:
                # new branch from root
                path = []
                value_found = False
            path.append(tag)

list(parse_tree(tags, values))
```

gives

```
[
    ('OAuth.UserAuth.Vendor', 'ABC'),
    ('OAuth.UserAuth.Time', '21.04'),
    ('Request', 'Temporary')
]
```